# How to use autorun.inf without upsetting anti-virus software?

Tags: autorun, compact-disc

I wish to use `autorun.inf` on a CD so that it auto-plays an installation package.

But I know that anti-virus software doesn't like `autorun.inf` files.  How can I use an `autorun.inf` file without upsetting anti-virus software?

Comment: Most auto run inf files are disabled from running in Windows now, has nothing to do with 3rd party security software, its blocked in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus have no problem with `autorun.inf` files... antivirus have problem with what is inside the `autorun.inf` file.

In Windows7 `autorun` is disabled on flash drives because Malware embeds itself on them pretty easy. But you can use `autorun` on a CD like normal.

Use [Microsoft Guidelines](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818804) on how to populate an autorun.

Using things like regedit, disabling UAC and other administration type actions will be flagged as suspicious by most anti virus scanners...

Answer (score 0):

Virus scanners and alike should have no problems with the `autorun.inf` on a CD.

Windows and third party applications alike usually limit themselves to blocking `autorun.inf` on memory cards, flash drives, etc.